# How to get element number when looping through a VBA Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have this VBA code that loops through an array (in this case, supplier_reports()) and it works fine. I was wondering if anyone know if there is a way to get the element number when working with the value in the array:

```
For Each x In supplier_reports

Workbooks.Open (x)

element_number = x

next x
```

In this case element number just becomes the value of x, not it's element number in the array.

Thanks

Comment: You need to have another variable as a counter that increments at the end of each loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a For Loop instead of For Each.

Eg.

```
For I = LBound(supplier_reports) To UBound(supplier_reports)
 Workbooks.Open (supplier_reports(I))
 element_number = I
Next
```

Comment: Good idea, I wasn't crazy about using a different structure, but this isn't a bad idea.

Comment: Thomas, In case of For Each as well, index is maintained internally. So no performance / memory loss also will be there.